# datagridview automatically converting string to double

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, sqldatatypes

I am trying to insert data from my datagridview to sql server but while saving the datatype of "material" is changing to double column

1. I have double checked the datatype at my sql server
   [image]
2. I have double checked the datatype at dataset designer also
   [image]

still while saving this is the end result

[image]

Please guide how to solve this .

Datagrid column proprty:
[image]
i am using "ADGV" nugget for datagridview

Comment: How have you defined your grid columns?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank for your reply ..i have added property image in the above question

Comment: Are you sure that's the Material Column with that float value? Electrode isn't a material, it's a tool; I suspect that column is actually your `Tool_Life` column; which *is* a floating point value (and the other 2 columns are your `Tool_Code` and `Tool_Description` columns).

Comment: @Larnu yes it is '''Material''' column which is  showing double type .The three columns shown in snip are SL_No , Type & Material

Comment: I suppose the lead on question then is why are you storing numerical data in a `nvarchar` column?

Comment: because sometime sit will be like "A1234567"

Comment: The issue could be the driver.  That is why you should use parameters when using SqlClient and define the data types of the variables.

Comment: @jdweng can you pls show how to do the same?

Comment: Post your query.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, however, how is the code getting the data from the DB to the GRID? It appears the “Material” data is stored in the DB is a “STRING” type. It also appears you may have added the columns to the grid manually. Therefore, there MUST be something in your code that is changing this “Material” `string` value to a `double` value… The grid is NOT going to “automatically” change the column type on its own. Can you show how the data is added to the GRID and possibly the query to get the data.

Comment: @JohnG:Thank you for your reply ..i have now solved the issue thanks for all of your suggestions , the data type was saved as double at table adapter source code and i changed the same to string.